# Is there a PPAD algorithm for computing primes that sum to even numbers?

Tags: complexity-classes, nt.number-theory

Goldbach's conjecture states that every even number greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of 2 primes.

I'm interested in this function problem:

**Given an even natural number *n* greater than 2, find a natural number *p* such that *p* and *n* - *p* are both prime.**  (Inputs that are not even natural numbers may be mapped to 0.)

If we assume that Goldbach's conjecture is true, this function f(*n*) = *p* is a member of TFNP.  The reason for this is that we are guaranteed by our assumption that Goldbach's conjecture is true that there exists an answer to the problem, and we can easily guess this answer (it is no greater in size than *n*), and then verify its accuracy in linear time.

Can we do any better than TFNP here?  Could there be some algorithm in PPAD that computes this, or could there even be an FP algorithm?

Comment: The problem is most likely in TFZPP, and specifically, the trivial algorithm that repeats choosing a random $p$ until it finds one that works should succeed in expected polynomial time (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification). However, I don’t think the Goldbach conjecture as such is strong enough to imply this.

Comment: And of course, if you throw in the usual derandomization assumptions, this means the problem is likely in FP.

Comment: PPAD is not really an algorithm, I think it would be better if you phrased your question as whether finding a prime is in PPAD.

Comment: I meant whether finding a prime is in PPAD.  I thought this was standard, but will change it if it's confusing.

Comment: An FP algorithm also follows from the conjecture (Granville, Van de Lune, Te Riele http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/Goldbach1.pdf) that the least $p$ is of order $O((\log n)^2\log\log n)$.

Comment: Interesting...which page of that paper is that conjecture on?  I am also trying to figure out if Bertrand's postulate is relevant, i.e., if one could simply find and step through all of the possible primes in polynomial time.  (Edit:  I found the conjecture, it's at the very bottom of the page...it's a little hard to understand for me to understand though, as I'm unfamiliar with the notation used in defining F_k.)

Comment: Well, showing that this problem is in PPAD would prove Goldbach's conjecture (since by definition a solution to the search problem must always exist.) So I don't see any way for PPAD to help understand this problem. You could try to construct some graph such that a sink is any prime $p$ such that $n-p$ is also prime, which then shows the problem is in PPAD iff Goldbach's. But I don't see how this helps you understand or solve the problem better...

Comment: I doubt that it lies in PPAD even if the conjecture is true. The reason is that usually in PPAD the number of solutions is odd. Here the number of solutions is obviously even (unless $n=2p$ that can be easily checked). So, if it can be reduced to EndOfALine, then the reduction must merge some solutions.

Comment: @Daniil If it lies in FP, it also lies in PPAD...

Comment: What if I instead ask to decide for an input even $n$ whether it is the sum of two primes? Of course, if Goldbach is true, this problem is in P, but maybe there is an algorithm that doesn't assume Goldbach holds.